# Microsoft Access VBA Datediff error

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

I get an Error at the if condition (I am guessing in the date diff), but I can't think of the reason why.

**The error states:** Invalid procedure call or argument.

Now: *Is the current system time in the format DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS*

datum: *Is a date from a table in the format DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS*

```
Public Function ImportDateCheckSpec(eing As String) As error
    Dim datum As Date
    Dim error As New error
    error.Success = True
    error.Code = 2
    error.Message = "There has been a problem with the given Date. This might be due to:" + vbCrLf + "   *The date is befor the current date. " + vbCrLf + "   *The date is in the wrong format."

    Debug.Print 4

On Error GoTo Fail
    datum = CDate(eing)
    Debug.Print datum
    Debug.Print Now

    If (DateDiff("Day", Now, datum) < 0) Then '<----- Here is the error
        Debug.Print 2
        error.Success = False
        Set ImportDateCheckSpec = error
    End If
    Exit Function

Fail:
    Debug.Print 3
    error.Success = True
    Set ImportDateCheckSpec = error
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: `Day` is not valid: `DateDiff("d", Now, datum)` - note `"99999"` would pass your test ...

Comment: `Error` is a keyword, you are strongly advised to change it with something else. Better off start using `Option Explicit` in your module declaration. Goto Options >> Require Variable Declaration to activate it.

Comment: Thank you, why would "99999" pass?

Comment: Will change that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter is incorrect on DateDiff.  Try this instead:

```
If (DateDiff("d", Now, datum) < 0) Then '<----- Here is the error
```